# selector for a UIDatePicker with args (UITextfiled)

Tags: objective-c, datepicker, selector

I've seen a lot of text fields with triggering a datepicker.
I want have only one method to make a datepicker. This datepicker must have a method selector with the identifier of the text fields. I don't know how can i make this.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)launchPickerDate:(id)sender{
    UIDatePicker *datepickerNew = [UIDatePicker new];
    [datepickerNew setHidden:NO];
    datepickerNew.frame =  CGRectOffset(datepickerNew.frame, 0, 244);

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    UIDatePicker *launchPickerDate = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [launchPickerDate addTarget:self action:@selector(SelectDatePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [actionSheet addSubview:launchPickerDate];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Ok"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeDatePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get your question but it seems to me you want to make some changes to your date picker based upon the text field selected. You can recognize the textfield from which the method was called using the `tag` property. Like

```
if (sender.tag==1){
//do something as first text field selected
}else if(sender.tag==2){

//do something as second text field selected
}
```

you can specify the tags for text field either by interface builder(if you are using xib's) or via code like. `firstTextField.tag=1;`
and so on.. hope this helps... if anything else just let me know

Comment: Ok for tag but how can i pass this param because my code is:
`[launchPickerDate addTarget:self action:@selector(SelectDatePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Comment: It's OK !

For all:

I have added 

    `launchPickerDate.tag = sender.tag;`

And 

    `- (IBAction)SelectDatePicker:(UIDatePicker*)sender{
    
        UITextField* tmp = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag];
        NSDate *date = [sender date];
        NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
        tmp.text = [formatter stringFromDate:date];   
}`